# Email not sending to outlook.com

Tags: php

I have a php mail set up to send, and it works completely fine on @gmail.com, but for some reason it doesn't reach any outlook e-mail.
I'll post my header, because I assume the problem is here

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Me < '.$email_from.' >' . "\n";
```

I've tried using it without variables, without from, with reply_to, but nothing seems to reach outlook. Any guess on where the problem might be? Thanks in advance

Comment: Outlook might not accept your mail as I don't fell like it contains DKIM and other Mail signing things. Maybe check your spam folder in Outlook. Using PHPMailer/Swiftmailer could get this issue resolved, but there are a lot more with them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not passing MS security checks.

Try and use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and SMTP. it'll pass more security filters but still may appear in the Junk folder.